# Http request with image body on angular7

Tags: angular, http

I am developing an angular application that takes a capture from webcam  every second and send it to rest api end point to make some magic analysis on it. To do this; I am making an interval observable that takes a capture from video recoded from the webcam and embedded it in the body of post http request (on base 64) to send it to the end point. This is how I am doing things:

app.component.ts

```
secondsCounter = interval(1000);

@ViewChild("video")
public video: ElementRef;

url = "http://myapi.com";
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/octet-stream',
    })
};

public capture() {
    let image = this.video.nativeElement
    return this.canvas.nativeElement.toDataURL("image/png"); 
}

getData(image): Observable<any>
{
   return this.http.post<any>(this.url, image, this.httpOptions)
}

public ngAfterViewInit() {
    if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(stream => {
             this.video.nativeElement.srcObject = stream;
             this.video.nativeElement.play();
        });

    }   
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.secondsCounter.subscribe(n =>
    {
      try {
        let image = this.capture();
        this.getData(image).subscribe(
          data => {
             console.log( data);
          }
        );

    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error: ",error);
    }
  });
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <video #video id="video" autoplay></video>
</div>
```

When I launch the application I get an 400 Error

> error: {…}
>   code: "BadRequestImageFormat"
>   message: "Bad Request Image Format, Uri: cde9bdf3442b45dc85256454f65ea068"

But when I test my end point with a http client like Insomnia or Fiddler Everything works right, How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Did you try - Content-Type: image/png..?

Comment: @MukulSharma: my api accept image through application/octet-stream and I tryied the same request body structure with Insomnia (http client) and it worked fine. The problem appear only with angular

Comment: I'm not sure capture() truly capture. Looks like you're posting the html element ?

Comment: @DouglasLiu: edited but still cannot work

Comment: @MèhdiBenHamida I never used these API before, but I don't think getDataURL() will give you the binary data you're expecting. This is actually a string. Does your endpoint support decoding from the string? It should be base64 encoded.

Comment: @DouglasLiu: How to do it then?

Comment: @MèhdiBenHamida I'd recommend you to encode an image and test it with your api. For example you may use this site: https://www.base64-image.de/. The string is exactly what you would get from getDataURL(). However, judging from your edit, you seem to get this sorted already ?

Comment: @DouglasLiu: I didn't get you question, What sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change capture() method to :
This is an example from my code : updating profile picture. I made some modifications...

```
public capture() {

let encodedBase64Picture : any ;
var file: File = this.video.nativeElement ;
var reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = ( e ) => {
encodedBase64Picture = reader.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL( file );
return encodedBase64Picture  ;
```

Comment: does `base64Reader` need some special package to import?

Comment: no package should exist cuz base64Reader = reader. I updated my code.

Comment: still does not work, I got "Argument 1 of FileReader.readAsDataURL does not implement interface Blob." error in code line `reader.readAsDataURL( file )`